# utf8 jquery and ie

Tags: php, jquery, internet-explorer, encode

hi i use this code for save text in database

```
function commenttext()
{
  var com=document.getElementById("commenttext").value;
  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
  else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
      document.getElementById("commentpalm").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","func/comment.php?comtext="+com,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
  document.getElementById("commenttext").value="";
}
```

and when i see database field in mysql admin insteat of utf8 charecter ???? save . 
this broblem only foe ie and in firefox or chrome is good . 
i use for all page this code

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

and my encodin is uft8 without BOM .

this broblem is only for IE .

Comment: It's a common problem, IE will often times use cp1252 if not everything is set to UTF-8, so you probably forgot something. Did you set mysql_set_encoding to UTF-8 aswell ?

Comment: salam vaghti ba jquery tooye ie ersal mikonam jaye kalamat ???? save mishe tooye database

Comment: i use : mysql_query("SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci'");

Comment: check this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/bf154d89-f3dd-4e31-9587-0226eca75541

Comment: vanu this is for ie7 and encoding i use all ie and have problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

and add this line to your `php.ini`:

```
  default_charset = "utf-8"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<meta>` tag rarely really helps if the header that you define in there is already sent by the web server. Put this at the top of your PHP application:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

Comment: Eh ... how can it work once and then stop working again? What has changed?